# Django testcase to test models failing

Tags: python, django

I am writing a test case for my model to test the `__str__` but apparently it is failing.

Here is my **tests.py**:

```
from todoapp.models import User, Task
from django.test import TestCase


class UserModelTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            first_name='john',
            last_name='doe',
            email='abc@example.com',
            password='johndoe')

    def test_string_representation(self):
        object_name = User.objects.get(id=50)
        expected_object_name = object_name.email
        self.assertEqual(expected_object_name, str(object_name))
```

Here is my **models.py**:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**P.S.**:
A user with `id=50` already exists

Comment: If the test is failing, please show the output when you run the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django creates a test database when you run the test, so it sounds like the user with `id=50` *doesn't* exist in the test database.

You are already creating a user in the `setUp` method, so I suggest you fetch that user in the test.

```
def test_string_representation(self):
    object_name = User.objects.get(email='abc@example.com')
    expected_object_name = object_name.email
    self.assertEqual(expected_object_name, str(object_name))
```

Note that you shouldn't usually rely on the id when fetching objects during tests. The id can change from run to run, for example if the tests run in a different order.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Btw is the `setUp` method compulsory ? What should my code be if I omit it ?

Comment: If you remove the `setUp` method, then you'll have to create the user somewhere else, otherwise `User.objects.get(...)` will fail. The `setUp` method runs before every test in the class. If you have more than one test in the class, then putting `User.objects.create(...)` in the `setUp` method means you don't have to repeat it in every test method. Django also has [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) which can be faster if you have lots of tests in the test class.

Comment: Gotcha ! Thanks mate :)